# Using octave to map vector values

Tags: matlab, vector, dictionary, octave

Can anyone explain how the following code:

`Y(Y==0) = -1`

sets all values of 0 to -1. For example for:

`Y = [1   1   1   0   0   0   1]`

we get:

`Y = [1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   1]`

What is confusing me is that `Y==0` does not return a vector of indices.
An if I try to use the vector `Y==0` directly I get the error:

`Y([0   0   0   1   1   1   0]) = -1`

`error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals`

I would have naturally opted for:

`Y(find(Y==0)) = -1`

and would like to know why the above does not use `find`

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called logical indexing. There is some documentation on gnu.org (see [4.6 Logical Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Logical-Values.html)), but the best place to find info about it is probably in the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Your example does not work because you are using an array of doubles, instead of a logical array, to index into `Y`. Consider the following (using Octave 3.6.2):

```
>> Y = [1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
Y =

   1   1   1   0   0   0   1

>> idx = Y==0
idx =

   0   0   0   1   1   1   0

>> idx_not_logical = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
idx_not_logical =

   0   0   0   1   1   1   0

>> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name                 Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====                 ====                     =====  =====
        Y                    1x7                         56  double
        ans                  1x7                          7  logical
        cmd_path             1x489                      489  char
        gs_path              1x16                        16  char
        idx                  1x7                          7  logical
        idx_not_logical      1x7                         56  double

Total is 533 elements using 631 bytes

>> Y(idx_not_logical)=-1
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals

>> Y(idx)=-1
Y =

   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1   1
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the explanation. Think the link MATLAB documentation is incorrect though. Seems to point back to this page. Maybe you were referring to something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 2):

`Y==0` returns a `bool matrix` as shown by:

```
> typeinfo(Y==0)
ans = bool matrix
```

That's why you can't index directly with `[0 0 0 1 1 1 0]`, which is a `matrix`:

```
> typeinfo([0 0 0 1 1 1 0])
ans = matrix
```

If you wish to convert to boolean, use `logical()`:

```
> typeinfo(logical([0 0 0 1 1 1 0]))
ans = bool matrix
```