# Why is a Boolean selector for rows not working in Octave if it is manually crafted, instead than built from an expression?

Tags: matlab, select, matrix, rows, octave

I am using the free Matlab clone *Octave*.

Unfortunately I have some problems with row selection. For example, having the following matrix `a`:

```
>> a
a =

    1        2        3        4        5
    1        2        1        2        1
```

I can build a selector as following:

```
>> bar = a(:,4) > 3
bar =

    1
    0
```

The selector `bar` works correctly when applied to `a`:

```
>> a(bar,:)
ans =

    1        2        3        4        5
```

But, if I build by hand a seemingly identical selector `foo`:

```
>> foo = zeros(2,1)
foo =

    0
    0

>> foo(1,1) = 1
foo =

    1
    0
```

Then this selector is unable to select from the matrix `a`:

```
>> a(foo,:)
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354201/using-octave-to-map-vector-values/20354634#20354634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example gives a `logical` vector, which can be used for [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/). Your second example, however, gives a `double` vector. Try `foo = logical(foo);` before `a(foo,:)`.

This is how it works in Matlab. I'm assuming it's the same in Octave.

Comment: Thank you! It indeed worked :) So it was just a matter of vector *type*. Do you know how to get the type of a vector? I assume that Matlab is not using *duck-typing*

Comment: @francescostablum `class(foo)`. Also, `islogical(foo)`, `isnumeric(foo)`, ... Anyway, when you build a vector from a relational operator as in your first example, you can be sure Matlab gives you a _logical_ vector